# React Component Not Recognizing Subdata from Prop Object

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React project where I need to display data received from a server in a table component. The data is passed to the component as a prop, but I'm encountering an issue where subdata of this prop is showing as undefined.

Problem Description:

The main data object (summaryData) is logged correctly in the console, but its subdata (summaryData.columns and summaryData.data) are logged as undefined.
I have tried accessing the subdata using both dot (.) and bracket ([]) notation.
The component should return a table with the data, but due to this issue, it's returning an error message for invalid or missing data.

```
import React from 'react';

const CalorySimulationTable = ({summaryData, onSelectOption }) => {

  const columns = summaryData ? summaryData.columns : [];
  const data = summaryData ? summaryData.data : [];

  console.log("summaryData for graph:", summaryData); // 'summaryData'를 콘솔에 로깅합니다.
  console.log("summaryData.columns:", summaryData.columns); // 'summaryData.columns'를 콘솔에 로깅합니다.
  console.log("summaryData.data:", summaryData.data); // 'summaryData.data'를 콘솔에 로깅합니다.
  console.log("column for graph:", columns); // 'summaryData'를 콘솔에 로깅합니다.
  console.log("data for graph:", data); // 'summaryData'를 콘솔에 로깅합니다.
  if (!summaryData || !Array.isArray(summaryData['columns']) || !Array.isArray(summaryData['data'])) {
    return <div>Invalid or missing data.</div>;
  }
  const formattedColumns = summaryData.columns.map(col => col.toString()); // 숫자를 문자열로 변환
    return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
        {formattedColumns.map((col, index) => <th key={index}>{col}</th>)}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {summaryData.data.map((row, rowIndex) => (
          <tr key={rowIndex}>
            {row.map((cell, cellIndex) => (
              <td key={cellIndex}>{cell}</td>
            ))}
            <td>
              <button onClick={() => onSelectOption(summaryData.columns[rowIndex])}>
                Select
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default CalorySimulationTable;
```

Console Output:

```
summaryData for graph: {"columns":[6300,8400,10500,12600,14700,16800], ...}
summaryData.columns: undefined
summaryData.data: undefined
column for graph: undefined
data for graph: undefined
```

Attempts to Resolve:

Tried using both dot and bracket notation to access subdata.
Removed conditional statements to see if they were causing the issue.
Questions:

Why are summaryData.columns and summaryData.data showing as undefined even though summaryData itself is logged correctly?
What changes should I make to properly access these subdata so that they can be used to render the table?
Any guidance or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I found the reason why this is happen.

I tried this to certify the type of data.

  console.log("calorySimulationData.data:", calorySimulationData.data); // 'summaryData.data'를 콘솔에 로깅합니다.
  console.log("calorySimulationData[0]:", calorySimulationData[0]); 
  console.log("calorySimulationData[1]:", calorySimulationData[1]); 
  console.log("calorySimulationData[2]:", calorySimulationData[2]); 

the console data are '{ ' , ''', 'c'
these are not index but string.

So I added this code to parsing the data to object.

 const calorySimulationData = JSON.parse(simulationResponse.data);

Comment: Post your finding as a normal answer-post and mark it as accepted, so that other users can see clearly and properly formatted the solution of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use in useState and useEffect:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

...
const [columns,setColumns] = useState([]);
const [data ,setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
   if(sammeryData){
     setColumns(sammeryData.columns);
     setData(sammeryData.data);
   }
},[])
```